# Given an ordered set, find the infimum and supremum of one of its subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I am given a an ordered set $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \subseteq)$ I need to find the infimum and supremum of its subset $A= \{ \{ 3,5,8 \}, \{1,2,3,5 \}, \{5,10 \} \}$.

Now, I am having quite a dilemma. From what I know, the element $S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is the minorant of $A$ if for each $y \in A$ we have that $S \subseteq y$.

1. Regarding infimum: From what I understand, the lower bounds would be for example $ \{ 5\}$ and $\emptyset$. But now, the definition of infimum is the "greatest" out of those. How can I "measure" which one out of $ \{ 5\}$ and $\emptyset$ is greater?
2. Regarding supremum, I need upper bounds. An upper bound would be an element from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ so that every element of $A$ is a subset of it. But still, I can think of many subsets of N for which this holds, the first one would be $ \{ 1,2,3,5,8,10 \} $. But still, how can I be certain that this is the supremum?

Comment: The word 'greater' for an ordered set refers to the relation (similar to how in a vector space the word 'vector' means an element of the vector space and 'addition' refers to one of the binary operations -- the words are abstract but filled in by the structure). So how to measure which of $\{5\}$ and $\varnothing$ is greater? Use $\subseteq$.

Comment: @KyleMiller Does that mean that {5} is greater than the empty set because the empty set is the subset of {5}, while the opposite is not true?

Comment: For your second question, the definition of upper bound and the definition of $\subseteq$ will allow you to prove that $\{1,2,3,5,8,10\}$ is a subset of all upper bounds. For example, an upper bound $U$ will have to satisfy $\{3,5,8\}\subseteq U$, but then $3\in\{3,5,8\}\subseteq U$ gives that $3\in U$. You can do the same for all other elements of $\{1,2,3,5,8,10\}$.

Comment: No need for "while the opposite is not true", but yeah, it's nothing more than that $\varnothing \subseteq \{5\}$.

Comment: In a power-set algebra infimum = intersection and supremum = union.

Comment: Also I don't understand this @NDB. I thought that by giving {1,2,3,5,8,10} I found the set with the least amount of elements that satisfies the condition that every element of $A$ is its subset, which would make it the "smallest" upper bound.

Comment: Well, comparing cardinality (number of elements) is related to your order relation $\subseteq$, but not the same relation. If $A\subseteq B$ then $|A|\leq |B|$, but not the other way around. To verify a supremum with respect to $\subseteq$ you need to check its definition. Perhaps there is another $5$ element set that is an upper bound!?

Answer (score 1):

In any power set ordering $(P(S), \subseteq) $:

- $Z$ being an "upper bound" of a collection
  $\mathcal A\subseteq P(S)$ means for all $X\in \mathcal A,$ $X\subseteq Z.$
- This means the same thing as $\bigcup_{X\in A} X\subseteq Z$
- $Y$ is the *least* upper bound for $\mathcal A$ iff $Y\subseteq Z$ for every upper bound $Z$ for $\mathcal A$
- So, $Y=\bigcup_{X\in A} X$ is the least upper bound of $\mathcal A.$

Similarly, the infimum of $\mathcal A$ is $\bigcap_{X\in \mathcal A} X.$

---

More generally:

If $\mathcal B$ is any collection of sets whatsoever, and $\mathcal A\subseteq \mathcal B,$ then in $(\mathcal B,\subseteq),$ we have  $\bigcup_{X\in \mathcal A}X = \sup\mathcal A$ *provided $\bigcup_{X\in \mathcal A}X\in\mathcal B$.*

If $\bigcup_{X\in \mathcal A}X\notin\mathcal B,$ then there could be a smallest set in $\mathcal B$ containing it, which would be the sup, or there could not, in which case the sup doesn't exist.

(And similarly for intersection/inf.)